# How Can I provide a custom domain name to my user under my domain

Tags: dns

I am building an web application where different users will be able to register. Right now an user of my application has the homepage url like `www.example.com/username`. But I want to provide `www.username.example.com` like url for the user. Is there any easy way to do this? Or I have to provide new machine with new domainname to the customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to configure DNS CNAME record for `www.username.example.com` that is pointing to `www.example.com`. That way all requests for `www.username.example.com` will go to your web server. You can do this for each username or perhaps with wildcard *.example.com

Next, you need to configure your webserver to respond to requests that have Host: www.username.example.com header (or again, go with the wildcard).

If the above two steps are done, since DNS handles only domain names, you need rewrite rule which depends on your webserver but for apache something like this should do:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```